# how to get Style.css , other CSS and javascript files of a Live website (single Page Website)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to solve some of issues of a live website(single page website) but I am not able to get its Style.css , other css and javascript files.I have got its html file by Ctrl+s but I am not able to get CSS and javascript files related to that website from chrome browser.

Please help me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can view all the sources for a website in chrome if you right click, and then press inspect. Then go to the sources tab. From there you can view the javascript and css files being used on that site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on any page.
2. click on view page source.
3. Then check for css and javascript codes in  section.
4. Better option is to search for that on source page - ".css" and ".js".

Note : Remove quotes when u search

Answer (score 0):

You can add your files directly to the `head` tag.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>form working<title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="your_filename_path.css">
    <script src="your_js_script_path.js"></script>
  </head>
<html>
```